# Custom permission failing on Motorola devices

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, user-permissions

I wrote a custom permission for receiving broadcasts for my widget, I get a permission denial for Motorola devices.

> Creating permission

```
<permission
    android:name="com.sample.app.WIDGET_PERMISSION"
    android:description="@string/widgetDesc"
    android:label="@string/widgetLabel"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" >
</permission>
```

> Adding permission to Manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sample.app.WIDGET_PERMISSION" />
```

> Adding receiver

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyWidget" android:label="MyApp"
                android:icon="@drawable/image" 
                android:permission="com.sample.app.WIDGET_PERMISSION">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                     <category android:name="com.sample.app" />
                </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

> I get permission denial message only for Motorola devices,

```
07-17 11:48:18.781: W/ActivityManager(479): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED cmp=com.sample.app/.MyWidget} from android (pid=3116, uid=10006) requires com.sample.app.WIDGET_PERMISSION due to receiver com.sample.app/com.sample.app.MyWidget

07-17 11:48:18.781: W/ActivityManager(479): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE cmp=com.sample.app/.MyWidget(has extras) } from android (pid=3116, uid=10006) requires com.sample.app.WIDGET_PERMISSION due to receiver com.sample.app/com.sample.app.MyWidget

07-17 11:48:18.828: W/ActivityManager(479): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=com.motorola.blur.home.ACTION_SET_WIDGET_SIZE cmp=com.sample.app/.MyWidget(has extras) } from com.motorola.blur.home (pid=3116, uid=10006) requires com.sample.app.WIDGET_PERMISSION due to receiver com.sample.app/com.sample.app.MyWidget
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `android:permission="com.sample.app.WIDGET_PERMISSION"` from your receiver tag and only include `<uses-permission android:name="com.sample.app.WIDGET_PERMISSION" />` under your manifest tag, outside any application and activity.

**EDIT:** The problem is that the broadcaster should send the permission together with the broadcast so that it passes through your BroadcastReceiver. When you are testing it using the command line, somehow, the permission is not being sent.

I think what you are doing about declaring the permission inside your receiver is correct but the issue is because of your permission protection level being signature. This level is described in the Android developers page like this:

> A permission that the system grants only if the requesting application
>   is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared
>   the permission. If the certificates match, the system automatically
>   grants the permission without notifying the user or asking for the
>   user's explicit approval.

This leads me to think that, in Motorola devices, this is not satisfied somehow. Try changing

```
android:protectionLevel="signature"
```

to

```
android:protectionLevel="normal".
```

If it still doesn't work, I would say there is a bug with Motorola configurations.

Comment: Then it works. But having this permission is not to receive from senders who don't have this permission. My code works on Samsung, Htc devices, the prob is only with Moto DroidX and Moto Bionic

Comment: From official Android Developers page: If this attribute (android:permission) is not set, the permission set by the <application> element's permission attribute applies to the broadcast receiver. If neither attribute is set, the receiver is not protected by a permission.

Comment: If an application needs access to a feature protected by a permission, it must declare that it requires that permission with a <uses-permission> element in the manifest. Then, when the application is installed on the device, the installer determines whether or not to grant the requested permission by checking the authorities that signed the application's certificates and, in some cases, asking the user. If the permission is granted, the application is able to use the protected features. If not, its attempts to access those features will simply fail without any notification to the user.

Comment: To test the broadcast receiver, I send a broadcast using this command, am broadcast -a com.sample.app.WIDGET_REFRESH     If it is using the permission, it shouldn't respond to this command as its not the same process. To prevent it from accepting it, we need to use the permission in the receiver. If you look at this site, https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/#manifest Google recommends to use permission in the receiver to receive broadcasts from particular receiver only.

Comment: It looks like there is a bug in Motorola specific devices on certain phones like Bionic. It works well on Atrix. I don't see any solution than to remove the permission.